# How to invert elements from $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/(x^n-1)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^n-1)$ for primes $p$ dividing $q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $q=p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_s^{m_s}$ be a positive integer, and let $R_m$ ($m\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$) be the factor ring $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_m[x]}{(x^n-1)}.$$ I have a question:

> Is correct that if $\overline{f(x)}\in \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^n-1)}$ is invertible in each $R_{p_i}$ then $\overline{f(x)}$ is invertible in $R_q$?

I want any hint to solve this problem.

Comment: non-invertible equals to zero divisor in finite dimension algebra or finite ring， you can analyse what zerodivisors of $R_q$ are